# a small SQL query problem with SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select

SQL queries are still my weakest point, so here I am with yet another SQL question.

Imagine I have two tables: **auctions** and **bids**. Table auctions contains my auctions and table bids contains the list of bids for each auction.

Now I'm selecting values like this:

```
   SELECT
   `auction_title`,
   `auction_seo_title`,
   `auction_description_1`,
   `auction_unixtime_expiration`,
   `auction_startPrice`,
   MAX(`bids`.`bid_price`) as `bid_price`
   FROM
   `auctions`
   LEFT JOIN `bids` ON `auctions`.`auction_id`=`bids`.`bid_belongs_to_auction`
   ORDER BY
   `auction_unixtime_expiration`
   ASC
   LIMIT 5
```

The query works, but it's got a little catch to it: It selects only those auctions, which have **at least one** corresponding value inside the **bids** table. That means that if I have a new auction, which has no bids yet, the query doesn't return this auction, but I want it too!

I believe this is a very simple problem for anyone with at least above average SQL skills. I hope someone like that comes around :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: this may b problem due to `LIMIT`...did u try it without `LIMIT` or you should try with `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: The query you posted is invalid, there is a missing `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Since you're using `LEFT JOIN` - you have to get **all** auctions as a result with bids related to it or padded with nulls. So look carefully one more time ;-)

Comment: I tried all ``LEFT JOIN``, ``INNER JOIN`` and ``RIGHT JOIN``, no change. Also, ``LIMIT`` is not a problem, I have got only 3 auctions in testing, so 5 isn't changing anything.

Comment: @RiMMER  My guess is that you have a `GROUP BY bids.bid_belongs_to_auction` in your query... Also, `LIMIT` applies to all rows, so if you have 3 auctions with 10 bids each, the query will only return 1 auction with 5 bid rows.

Comment: The query you have is broken and won't run.  If you think that you are running it, then PEBKAC and you're actually running some other query.  You have to fix that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   `auction_title`,
   `auction_seo_title`,
   `auction_description_1`,
   `auction_unixtime_expiration`,
   `auction_startPrice`,
   MAX(`bids`.`bid_price`) as `bid_price`
FROM
   `auctions`
LEFT JOIN `bids` ON `auctions`.`auction_id`=`bids`.`bid_belongs_to_auction`
GROUP BY `auction_id`
ORDER BY `auction_unixtime_expiration` ASC
```

Give that a try. Assuming that works, you can add your LIMIT on to the end.

Comment: `GROUP BY` goes before `ORDER BY`